# ASP.NET file IO account

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net 3.5 app that write a zip file to a directory(Ionic Zip lib). this became a concern to my client that this could open up the server to attack. his logic was:

- my app uses ASPNET account to write
  the file
- ASPNET is a shared account that is
  used by other apps on the same
  server.
- therefore it could be dangerous to
  use it to write files. he didnt go into details.

is this true? if yes, what kinda attacks? and how do i prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that one should use an account setup with the least required privileges as the website account.

The ASPNET account has quite a lot of privileges, so there is indeed a concern right there.

However, the fact that is *writes* a file out doesn't make the files dangerous as such. It is possible that your client meant that it can be subverted to overwrite any file in the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

As for how to prevent it, you can set up your site in IIS to run under a different, unique account. Only give that account permission to write files into the intended directory.

You can do this by setting the site to run under a specific app pool, and then [configure that app pool to run under a specific identity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: so this is something a server admin would do. i don't have to do anything in my code.